# Google Script to delete row if date in certain cell is smaller than current date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a Google Script which checks once a day on my spreadsheet and copies the values to another sheet and than deletes all the rows if the date in that cell is small than the current.

The file looks like this:
[image]

And this is what I wrote so far:

```
function DeleteIfDateIsToSmall(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var today = new Date();
  var today2 = Utilities.formatDate(today,'GMT+0200','dd.MM.yyyy');
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1

  for (var i=2; i < numRows; i++) {
    var DateCell  = s.getRange(i, 13);  
    var sheetDate = DateCell.getValue()
    var sheetDate2 = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0200','dd.MM.yyyy');
    var row = i;
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ended or Deleted");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    if (s.getName() == "Start" && sheetDate != 0 && sheetDate != "" && today2.valueOf() > sheetDate2.valueOf()){
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(row); 
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work, please help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things are wrong or suboptimal here.

1. For a timed trigger, the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) does not have any range/source data; it only has time data. You need to pick a sheet by name (or loop through all sheets obtained by `getSheets`, if this is what you want).
2. `Utilities.formatDate` returns a string, which is not the best way to compare dates; in any case calling `valueOf` on it seems pointless.
3. Instead of using `getValue` in a loop, it is more efficient to obtain values before entering the loop, with `getValues`. There are some other things you do in the loop that should be outside.
4. Deleting rows when moving top to bottom in a sheet is tricky, because rows shift, messing up their indexing. For this reason, I collect the rows to be deleted in an array, and then delete them in bottom-to-top order.

---

```
function DeleteIfDateIsTooSmall() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Start");
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ended or Deleted");
  var today = new Date();
  var dates = s.getRange(2, 13, s.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var rowsToDelete = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (dates[i][0] && dates[i][0] < today) {
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      rowsToDelete.push(i + 2); 
    }
  }
  for (i = rowsToDelete.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    s.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[i]);
  }
}
```